# How to print Django's runserver output to a file?

Tags: django, logging

when i develop my django app locally, i use `python manage.py runserver` and all errors messages (like Error 500 ...) are printed in the terminal.
It is useful because it enables to put some `print`in the code and check the values of some variables.

But when the app is executed via fastgci on a remote server i can't see those messages.
Is there a way to output those errors in a file?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barring bugs in the web server, error messages generated by FastCGI apps should be logged in the web server's error log. Use your web server configuration options to control where the log is created.

And don't use `print`, use [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) instead.